# WordPress - Retrieve the logo address from a domain address

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to retrieve the address of the logo of a domain passed in parameter name.

For example, for the Quiksilver.fr site, the php function would return: http://demandware.edgesuite.net/aahh_prd/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-QS-FR-Library/default/dwe2126f9f/images/logo-qs@2x.png

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not mistaken [get_header_image()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header_image) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I can't get the address of my logo but the logo of a particular web site address.